# What is the Elastic equivalent of MongoDB Compass?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been asked to make some modifications to an existing app that uses Elastic Search.
I'm trying to find an data viewer for Elastic and while I've found several, they are not working for me.

With MongoDB, I've used something called RoboMongo and is now called [Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass).
Is there an equivalent type of data browser for Elastic?  If so what is it?

### What are some Elastic Search Viewers?

I searched for `elastic ui browser` and got many hits, some include:

- [https://www.slant.co/topics/11537/~elasticsearch-gui-clients](https://www.slant.co/topics/11537/%7Eelasticsearch-gui-clients) - A review of several clients.  Some I tried.
- https://github.com/elastic/eui - This is more of a kit so someone could build a UI
- Dejavu - tried this but needs cors enabled and I don't control the Elastic Search service.

```
docker run -p 1358:1358 -d appbaseio/dejavu
```

- Elastic Search Tools Chrome Extension
  See [Chrome WebStore for Elastic Search Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/elasticsearch-tools/aombbfhbleaidjmbahldfbajjmgkgojl?hl=en-US)
- Elastic Search HQ - See https://github.com/ElasticHQ/elasticsearch-HQ (no longer maintained)

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 elastichq/elasticsearch-hq
Then goto http://localhost:5000
```

- ElasticVue -  See https://elasticvue.com/ which has a Chrome Plugin

### Problem:

So far I've either not been able to login because I can't enter the username/password, or possibly because of CORS issues, or I'm connected and don't see any data.

I read that this is the syntax for entering a username/password in the Elastic URL

```
https://username:password@myelastic.example.com/
```

I'm thinking because of CORS, I'll need an app that is installed not something that is a browser plugin.

Comment: You could use [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/kibana/), the official visualization tool of the Elastic stack.

Comment: What's an easy way to install both ElasticSearch and Kibana?  Is installing the ELK stack the easiest thing to do?  If so, is it easier in a Linux dev box or in docker or k8s?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72236367/how-can-i-run-the-elastic-and-kibana-maybe-elk-stack-on-local-dev-box-k3s-mi for the full question

Comment: I do not run docker or k8s, but the easiest way would be using docker, check the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) on how to do that.

Comment: Did you find a good tool for this? Or is Kibana the only way to browse an ES cluster?